# What justifies using Java over Django/Python, PHP, etc. for the web?

Tags: java, php, django, spring

I'm currently studying the Spring framework and JDBC (re-studying this because I really, really want to understand Hibernate) to do some web development/web services as a summer intern. I've been curious for quite some time about what advantages Java/Spring (or just Java EE for that matter) has over Django, Rails, PHP, etc.

As far as I can see, the latter frameworks are far more effective for rapid development and some of them scale quite impressively. Based on one of the posts here:

[Web: When should I consider using Java rather than PHP, Python/Django, Ruby/Rails, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967137/web-when-should-i-consider-using-java-rather-than-php-python-django-ruby-rail)

There really is no obvious benefit to using Java. The answer is always "whichever one you feel most comfortable with." But I am interested in seeing what aspects of using Java frameworks is superior to that of the other listed frameworks and vice versa.

Comment: @julio.alegria I have now accepted the questions that were answered. I thought that voting for an answer was the way we provide feedback of some sort on this forum.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing.  Rails, PHP, and all of the Python frameworks can provide you with productive environments that perform well and scale.  The Spring Framework is very mature and the learning curve is a bit steeper - I believe there are 55+ jar files in one of their most basic samples.  Any experienced programmer will tell you that you are going to spend some time with each of them at some point, if you build a non-trivial web app.

What Spring buys you, generally, is a fairly sophisticated framework for building enterprise apps, e.g. when you are working with distributed systems and need to handle complex communications between apps.

So, the trade-off in frameworks is between support for functionality and ease of use.  There's no a priori proof or justification of any framework's superiority, and good developers are generally productive in any of them.

Comment: I would add: Each languages/runtime combo have advantages / disadvantages over the others. Pick the one you are the most comfortable with / want to use. None is perfect.

Comment: Ahh. So frameworks in Java arguably provides greater functionality at the expense of rapid development. Yes, I can definitely see that there's a LOT of "paper work" just to get something to work in Java/Spring/EJB. Could you please provide us with a specific example about Java's greater functionality? (Ex. What Java can do, but would be highly impractical to do in the other frameworks).

Comment: @Martin Samson - I am very keen on using the right tool for a specific job. I do not want to get type casted into a specific language in my career, so I plan to learn a very diverse range of languages and frameworks. I think asking questions such as the one that I asked would help those who are interested in evaluating whether Java would be a good choice for tackling a particular project.

Comment: @user1079776 Java is a great choice if you do not need a "rapid development environment". It just has a slower startup curve than CakePHP/RoR. Learn as many tools as you can. An example of a Java feature over php: Java applications usually offer application-wide, session and request states. PHP only offers session and request states. Java has a great threading system.

Comment: Being a longtime hibernate/spring java stack web app developer, I've been thrilled using the Grails framework. IMHO Grails gives you that rapid development environment that Rails offers.  Those experienced with Hibernate and Spring already will be glad to hear that Grails is just a framework running on top of them, and that Spring Source is the developer of the platform. Check it out.